# Ember defining actions, in controller vs in route

Tags: ember.js

From official guides:

> If the controller does not implement a method with the same name as
>   the action in its actions object, the action will be sent to the
>   router, where the currently active leaf route will be given a chance
>   to handle the action.

So what are pros & cons of defining actions methods in controller and defining actions methods in route? As i can see guides doesn't talk about that.
Defining in controller can be "faster" in sense of preventing action bubling.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Good question, although perhaps not an ideal fit for the SO format.

The simple answer is, **put routing-related actions in the router, and controller/model-related actions in the controller**.

If you find yourself calling `this.controllerFor` in the router action, or `this.get('target')` in the controller action, there's a good chance you've misplaced the action.

Transition-related actions are often a good choice for putting in the route. Actions such as modifying or saving a model likely belong in the controller.

Remember that actions bubble up from the leaf routes to parent routes. So if you want to define an action that applies to a group of children routes, it makes sense to put that in the parent route.

Comment: Hi @torazaburo, has anything changed since June 2014? Do you still recommend using actions on controllers or should we move everything to routes now that we have routable components?